# Reusing xml for-each blocks in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, variables, attributes

I have an attribute whose value is the XPath to the current node, like so:

```
<xsl:attribute name="path">
  <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
    <xsl:if test="name() != 'root'">
      <xsl:value-of select="name()">
        <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
          <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Is there a way to be able to reuse that block of code so I could just say.

```
<xsl:variable name="pathVariable">
  <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
    <xsl:if test="name() != 'root'">
      <xsl:value-of select="name()">
        <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
          <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

`<!-- a 100 places throughout the document -->
<xsl:attribute name="path">
  <xsl:value-of select="$pathVariable"/>
</xsl:attribute>`

The above variable declaration doesn't work, any ideas how to make it work?

Thanks so much,
Lance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could use a call to a named template to do what this

```
<xsl:template name="ancestors">
   <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
      <xsl:if test="name() != 'root'">
         <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
         <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
            <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

You can then simply call this from within the parameter.

```
<xsl:attribute name="path">
   <xsl:call-template name="ancestors" />
</xsl:attribute>
```

When you call the named template, the context remains as the current node, so it should work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:variable name="pathVariable">
  <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
    <xsl:if test="name() != 'root'">
      <xsl:element name="dummy"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></xsl:element>
      <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">
        <xsl:element name="dummy">/</xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- a 100 places throughout the document -->
<xsl:attribute name="path">
  <xsl:value-of select="$pathVariable/text()"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```